# Node.js App Engine to mySQL database not connecting

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have two App Engine projects hosting separate sections of my system (backend and client). Backend has a MySQL database and client has a Node.js App Engine project.

If I run the Node server locally I can connect the the SQL database via host:  however if I deploy the app to the app engine the connection does not work (502, Bad Gateway). I have made sure the IAM profile has been forwarded but still no luck getting it to work.

Anyone have any idea?

thanks.